# Python: TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5

Tags: python, typeerror

When I am trying to input get a number into the system I get an error.

```
userInput= int(input("What is", RanNum1," - ", RanNum2," = ?"))
```

That is the code in question and the error entails this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:/Project/MathProgram.py", line 144, in <module>
userAnswer = Addition(RanNum1, RanNum2)
File "H:/Project/MathProgram.py", line 33, in Addition
userInput= int(input("What is", RanNum1," - ", RanNum2," = ?"))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5
```

I have no idea why please help!!!

Comment: You might consider to learn to read the documentation. Look at [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and you'll see, that it takes only one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is five arguments being passed to `input`:

```
input("What is", RanNum1, " - ", RanNum2, " = ?")
```

Use the `str.format` method to provide a single string to input.

```
inputstring = "What is {0} - {1} = ?".format(RanNum1, RanNum2)
userInput= int(input(inputstring))
```

Answer (score 4):

`input` expects a single string, not 5 arguments.

You can use the `format` function to generate your string using these variables.

```
userInput= int(input("What is {} - {} = ?".format(RanNum1, RanNum2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error pretty clear... You're passing 5 arguments:

```
userInput= int(input("What is", RanNum1," - ", RanNum2," = ?"))
                         ^^^      ^^^    ^^^     ^^^     ^^^
                          1        2      3       4       5
```

Coming from Java, are we? **:-)**

If you want to display variables in an string in python, you can take a look to [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (what other answers use) or you could also do:

```
userInput= int(input("What is %s - %s = ?" % (RanNum1, RanNum2)))
```

Also, if you're running this using Python 2.x (any version less than 3) I strongly recommend using [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). Input will [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) the user's input as python code, and [eval is evil](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Although `print` optionally takes multiple argument, `input` doesn't.

You either need to use the `format` function - `userInput= int(input("What is {} - {} = ?".format(RanNum1, RanNum2))`, or add the values `userInput= int(input("What is" + str(RanNum1) + " - " + str(RanNum2) + " = ?"))` (the first option there is best).

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput= int(input("What is", RanNum1," - ", RanNum2," = ?"))

# replace comma , with plus sign +

userInput= int(input("What is"+ RanNum1+" - "+ RanNum2+" = ?"))

# it is how i fixed when i got the same error message 

balance = float(input("OK, ", name, ". Please enter the cost of the", item, ":"))

# to

balance = float(input("OK, "+ name + ". Please enter the cost of the " + item + ": "))
```